# Android Pull-to-Refresh with ListView Fragment & Custom ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment, pull-to-refresh

I built my project using the Android Studio start options (Automatically builds the `action bar` with the tabs) so a bit is generated for me. I did however implement a `list-view fragment` for each one of the tabs that uses custom `adapters`.

I'm having a trouble adding the pull-to-refresh lib from [Chris Bane](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/QuickStart-ABC). Maybe I'm importing it wrong? I'm fairly new at android development and especially with this new Gradle stuff.

I'm Importing the github repository in the build.gradle file here:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
   compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
 }
```

Everything minus the minSDKVersion & the last compile in dependencies was pre-generated when my project was created. This build.gradle file is the one in my `/app folder.

Gradle will sync properly and I will see files from the actionbar git in my .idea folder in the project root.

**Here is where I am getting confused:**

In the github repo "quick start" it says

> The first thing you need to do is wrap your refreshable view in a PullToRefreshLayout:

With a code example doing something like this:

```
<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarcompat.PullToRefreshLayout>
<listview/>
</uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarcompat.PullToRefreshLayout>
```

Is `uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras` suppose to be my projects name, so `com.lucaapp.app`?

Here is my XML for my ListFragment, where u'll see my confusion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.lucaapp.app.PullToRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ptr_layout" >


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />


<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="No Events" />

</com.lucaapp.app.PullToRefreshLayout>
```

This will not give me any errors immediately until I try to implement the code from the `quick start guide` in my fragment class. I get an `Cannot Resolve Symbol` error trying to import that github repo methods.

I've tried the following which makes the import red with `cannot resolve symbol` error:

```
import com.lucapp.app.PullToRefreshAttacher;
import com.lucapp.app.PullToRefreshLayout;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarcompat.PullToRefreshAttacher;
```

Comment: Why use  compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+' when you are using a minsdk=14? 
Use: compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to follow this tutorial from Chris Banes:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/QuickStart-ABS
?

This tutorial contains all steps, beginning from build.gradle and finishing with code snippets.

The only difference: tutorial is for ScrollView (not ListView as you wish). But don't be scared. Just replace ScrollView with ListView and everything should be OK.

**UPDATE:**
you should see at this block especially:

```
<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your content, here we're using a ScrollView -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ScrollView>

</uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout>
```

you should not use `com.lucaapp.app.PullToRefreshLayout` instead of `uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Now android has introduced new simple featrure called Swipe to refresh layout. Please refer the site [devloper site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)  and a [simple example](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/)