# How to refresh ListView when go to 0th position in android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I have one **ListView with BaseAdapter.**

Normally we see that **ListView that refresh when user go to 1st position and then If User swipe the Listview at upside from first position** then list of the ListView is refresh.

I want to apply that in android can any one tell me how it is possible ?

Comment: atleast clear your requirement then ask question. you want to apply pull to refresh functionality in your listview..

Comment: try this which is already posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543047/android-pull-to-refresh-with-listview-fragment-custom-listview-adapter

Comment: and this tutorial is very helpful depends on your requirement http://sharedstate.net/archives/pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 2):

Basically this is called **pull to refresh**.

this is a [good tutorials](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/) . Read here how to implement it.

and this is [one more.](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)

and you can read. [Swipe Refresh layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) to from developer.android.com